# Threaded Java server with inner class and final variable

Tags: java, sockets, final, anonymous-inner-class

I've written the following code to implement a Threaded Server:

```
ServerSocket passiveSocket = new ServerSocket(port, maxConnections);  
while(true){
  final Socket socket = passiveSocket.accept();                       
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          //access socket as needed to communicate. E.g.:
          PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
          //Finally close socket.
          socket.close();
      }
  }).start();
}
```

Now this seems to work, but in reflection I do not really understand what's going on with the final socket variable *socket* when the next connection arrives. How is each thread associated with the socket instance which was current when starting the thread? - is the *final* keyword  responsible for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it this way: `socket` is secretly passed as an argument to the `new Runnable` constructor, and it's kept as a variable in the anonymous `Runnable` class.  (That's actually how it works, at the bytecode level.)

The created `Runnable` object contains a reference to the one specific `Socket` value at its creation time, so it can close that specific socket when it's done.

Answer (score 2):

When passing a `final` variable to an anonymous inner class, that variable is effectively stored in the anonymous class as if it was an instance variable.

The code above could be effectively translated to:

```
private static final class RunnableAnonSubclass implements Runnable {
    private final Socket socket; 
    private RunnableAnonSubclass (Object socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        //access socket as needed to communicate. E.g.:
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        //Finally close socket.
        socket.close();
    }
}

// ... 
{ 
    ServerSocket passiveSocket = new ServerSocket(port, maxConnections);  
    while(true){
        Socket socket = passiveSocket.accept();               
        new Thread(new RunnableAnonSubclass(socket)).start();
    }
}
```

Notice that making a local variable `final` is the only way to access it inside an anonymous inner class. See [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/851811) on "[Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4732544/851811)" for details on the reasons.